# While adding new routes, I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, routes, playframework, limit

I am having a route file with around 900 routes. Starting today, while adding new routes, I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Can somebody help me to find out what is causing the error and how to solve it?

If I delete a couple of the routes, it works. So I guess I am hitting some kind of route limit.

Comment: Can you show us the complete error you're getting?

Comment: On a side note, 900 routes sounds really a lot. Are these really 900 different routes? In a single WS?!